# How do I upgrade my linkedin developer account from default package to developer or standard

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I recently signed up for a LinkedIn developer account which was granted successfully.
The account happens to have default access rights where only a few APIs can be access.

I would like to upgrade my package so that I am able to access the group, search for people and events apis.

At the moment, I get a 403 whenever I attempt accessing the group memberships API.

> {'serviceErrorCode': 100, 'message': 'Not enough permissions to access: GET-group /groupMemberships', 'status': 403}

I wrote to linkedin which in term responded with a couple of auto generated emails with reference number # 230828-017529.

One of the email requested me to ask the question from stackoverflow.

What I expected.
I expected to have a link to the form where I can upgrade to the desired linkedin developer package.

But nothing has worked for now 1 week.